# Python Pandas Dataframe efficient element-wise comparing by dropping columns

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I'm working on a len(df) = 100.000 dataframe which looks like this:

```
| ref_id | title           |
   01       "Test title"
   02       "Title 2"
   03       "Test Title"
```

I want to aggregate all ref_ids where the title has a levenshtein-ratio > 0.8

My function looks like:

```
def match_title(title_a, title_b):
   return True if Levenshtein.ratio(title_a, title_b) > 0.8 else False
```

Since i have to compare each title with each title it gets expensive (100k*100k). But i just thought about dropping already matched elements of my dataframe to fasten the calculation:

```
match = []
for element in df.itertuples():
    indices_series = df.apply(lambda x: match_title(
        x['title'], element.title), axis=1)
    indices = df[indices_series].ref_id.as_matrix()
    if indices.size:
        match.append(set(indices))
        df.drop(indices,inplace=True)
return match
```

So my output looks like this

```
[(01,03),(02)...]
```

Unfortunately it is still slow and needs ~3 seconds for each iteration which would lead to a total of 4 days.

Has anybody an advice how to speed this all up? Thank you for any help

Comment: You may get some value out of doing a `df['title_lower'] = df.title.applymap('lower'); df.groupby('title_lower')`, which will at least give you all the titles that exactly match (case insensitive). I don't know how many of these there are. Does your simplification work? L(abc, bcd) = 1, L(bcd, cde) = 1, but L(abc, cde) = 2, which in general may be a problem (i.e. do you group bcd's refid with abc, or cde?)

Comment: i expect to be the total amount of different titles 10 to 15k. Grouping as you suggested may be helpful since many strings are identical. But should i group first and afterwards iterate over these groups or how should i integrate this into the function?